# Python check if a file is already used by another proccess, if yes skip it

Tags: python, windows, file, process

Hi I'm looking for a Python code that checks if a file is already in use by another process and if it is, the script should skip that file.
I did not get any Error messages in my Script is just exits. (Im using Windows)

I've tried using;

```
            try:
                # x = the current file loaded from a for loop
                with open(x, "rb") as current_file:
                    file_content = current_file.read()
                    #doing some stuff
                with open(x, "wb") as current_file:
                    #write to file
            except e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
            continue
```

Comment: Any other process, or a process you have written the code for?

Comment: any other process, lets say I want to open Text.txt but it is already in use by another programm so my code should skip the opening for that file and continue with the next file.

Comment: wouldn't (try: ... except:) work?

Comment: by the way to print the exception you have to do 
except Exception as e:  
print(f"error: {e}")

Comment: No the Try ... except does not work it does not skip that file it only crashes the programm.
Thanks for the Exception as e: information